# Optimize SQL Query Using Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, inner-join

I was using 2 variables with a `SELECT` statement for each.

I was told that I could optimize my query by using `JOIN` to do the query just once.

I managed to combine the statement into one. But it did not use `JOIN`, and there are still 2 `SELECT` statements in my current query.

**Current query:**

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @EntityId int, @Country nvarchar(10), @OrganizationId int, 
@Username nvarchar(100) = 'user1'

Set @OrganizationId = (SELECT BU.OrganizationId 
FROM [Company].[Config].[BusinessUnit] BU 
WHERE BU.EntityId = (SELECT BU.EntityId
FROM [Company].[PES].[EmployeeProfile] EP
LEFT JOIN   Config.BusinessUnit bu on EP.EntityCode = BU.EntityCode
WHERE EP.Username = @Username))

IF(@OrganizationId = 3)
    SET @Country = 'MS'
ELSE
    SET @Country = 'SG'
SELECT @Country

END
```

Is my current query good to go, or can it be further improved? Thank you.

---

*Previous query:*

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @EntityId int, @Country nvarchar(10), @OrganizationId int, 
@Username nvarchar(100) = 'user1'

Set @EntityId = (SELECT BU.EntityId
FROM [Company].[PES].[EmployeeProfile] EP
LEFT JOIN   Config.BusinessUnit bu on EP.EntityCode = BU.EntityCode
WHERE EP.Username = @Username)

Set @OrganizationId = (SELECT BU.OrganizationId 
FROM [Company].[PES].[BusinessUnit] BU 
WHERE @EntityId = BU.EntityId)

IF(@OrganizationId = 3)
    SET @Country = 'MS'
ELSE
    SET @Country = 'SG'
SELECT @Country

END
```

Comment: Can you explain what the logic should be doing?  Sample data and desired results help.  Also, your code looks like SQL Server, not MySQL.  That affects optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not combine this into a single query?

```
SELECT @Country = (CASE WHEN @OrganizationId = 3 THEN 'MS'
                        ELSE 'SG'
                   END)
FROM [Company].[PES].[EmployeeProfile] EP JOIN
     Config.BusinessUnit cbu 
     ON EP.EntityCode = cbu.EntityCode JOIN
     [Company].[PES].[BusinessUnit] BU 
     ON cbu.EntityId = bu.EntityId
WHERE EP.Username = @Username)
```